# Limit Azure function auto scaling

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I would like to do a demo of an azure function webhook with auto scaling off and then switch it up to show how it scales automatically. Is there anyway I can set the maximum number of instances it scales to? I've looked through the settings for a Function App but can't find anything.

Answer (score 3):

Unlimited elastic scaling applies to Consumption Plan only. For your demo you can create two Function Apps: one on Consumption Plan, another one on "normal" fixed App Service Plan.

The fixed one will be limited to resources of that service plan, so to 1 instance by default.

I don't think you can switch the service plan between Consumption/Fixed for an existing app.

Comment: I've chosen a B1 basic service plan but there doesn't seem to be anything listed in the scaling out section. Is this where I am mean to set the scaling properties or is it limited just by the single core?

Comment: @johnstaveley Basic doesn't allow auto-scale. My idea was that you will use it for "non-scalable" scenario, and use Consumption Plan for "scalable" one.